# How to do this with while loop

Tags: bash

Problem is:

`grep` the output of `ps aux` for any instance of firefox, if firefox is already running, open link in new tab, if firefox is not running, start firefox and open the link.

Point to be noted here is that I have mentioned the count variable to be greater than 1 because `ps aux | grep firefox` itself is a process that would be listed, so any other instance other than that. When I run the following script it, goes into loop, what's the right logic?

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while [[ $(ps aux | grep firefox) ]]
do
    count=$((count+1)) ;
    if ( count -gt 1 )
        then    
            nohup firefox --new-tab "mega.nz" &
        else
            nohup firefox "mega.nz" &
    fi
done
```

**Edit : Thanks to the comments and answer below, they helped me get rid of the `while` loop totally by using `pgrep` as thrig and Deathgrip mentioned below, but how do I achieve this by `while` loop or let me know if this cannot be performed with `while` loop.**

Comment: `pgrep` can profitably replace `ps ... | grep ...`

Comment: You are not breaking out of the loop anywhere. Merely checking for a running `firefox` process, incrementing `count`, and either running a new `firefox` (first iteration), or opening a new tab (remaining iterations). Perhaps describe what you want to happen?

Comment: @Deathgrip Do `ps aux | grep --firefox`, now from the output, if firefox exists in more than 1 processes (2 or more lines on terminal), run the `if` loop and exit out of `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
if [[ $(pgrep firefox) ]]
then    
    nohup firefox --new-tab "mega.nz" &>/dev/null &
else
    nohup firefox "mega.nz" &>/dev/null &
fi
```

Your script edited, still not sure under what conditions you want to break out of the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while [[ $(ps aux | grep firefox) ]]
do
    count=$((count+1)) ;
    if [ $count -gt 1 ]
        then    
            nohup firefox --new-tab "mega.nz" &
            break
        else
            nohup firefox "mega.nz" &
    fi
done
```

Comment: Yes, learned this from the comments above, but am curious to know how to perform this with `while` loop instead or have someone explain if this cannot be performed by `while` loop

Comment: Okay, understood.. No, there is nothing important in while loop here, I understand but wanted to know how to do this the other way round. Thanks. I didn't know `break` exists in bash also. I have been coding in bash since last 2 weeks or so only. I am a new to linux.